# rails paperclip tinypng gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, paperclip

I installed gem: https://github.com/benmanns/tinypng

And in my class:

```
has_attached_file :photo <...>


  before_save :tiny_png_preprocessor

  private

  def tiny_png_preprocessor

    image_file = File.open(self.photo.path)
    client = TinyPNG::Client.new("#{tiny_png_api_key}") # tinypng api key
    image = client.shrink(image_file.read)
    image.input # => {"size"=>1234}
    image.output # => {"depth"=>8, "size"=>567, "ratio"=>0.459, "url"=>"http://tinypng.org/api/shrink/out/example.png"}
    temp_file = image.to_file # => #<File:/tmp/tinypng20120910-5552-aturxh.png>
    self.photo = temp_file

  end
```

I want `rake paperclip:refresh class=Photo` for preprocess all photos after paperclip save. How can I do that?

In my console after rake task:

```
rake aborted!
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
/mtfck/new_tamir/app/models/photo.rb:30:in 'initialize'
/mtfck/new_tamir/app/models/photo.rb:30:in 'new'
/mtfck/new_tamir/app/models/photo.rb:30:in 'tiny_png_preprocessor'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved

```
require 'net/https'
require 'uri'
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { large: '471x589',
                                         medium: '381x476',
                                         small: '284x355',
                                         thumb: '227x284'},
                    :default_url => '/images/:style/missing.png'

after_save :tiny_png_preprocessor

private

def tiny_png_preprocessor

    key = '%%%API_KEY%%%'

    arr = [:large, :medium, :small, :thumb, :original]

    arr.each do |style|

      input = self.photo.path(style)
      output = input

      uri = URI.parse('https://api.tinypng.com/shrink')

      http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
      http.use_ssl = true

      request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
      request.basic_auth('api', key)

      response = http.request(request, File.binread(input))
      if response.code == '201'
        File.binwrite(output, http.get(response['location']).body)
      else
        puts 'Compression failed'
      end
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

It' failing in your `before_save` and the `tiny_png_api_key` is `nil`

```
TinyPNG::Client.new(nil)
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
    from (irb):2:in `initialize'
    from (irb):2:in `new'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/ankitgupta/.rvm/rubies/ruby
```

Comment: I have tiny_png_api_key. just hide it. cos i'll want to pay for pro account tiny png. Sorry, if it mislead u.

Comment: @Legendary, what i am saying is , make sure your key is getting in.  Do a `logger.info` on the key

Comment: i have  | client = TinyPNG::Client.new('API_KEY_STRING_HERE') | without variable